# Derivative w/respect to parameter of a vector field along a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, curves, chain-rule

Given is the curve

$x(p)=\sin(p)$

$y(p)=\cos(p)$

$z(p)=p$

and a vector field $\mathbf{A}(p)$ defined on it as $\mathbf{A}(p)=\left(\begin{array}{c} \cos(p)\\  -\sin(p)\\  1\\ \end{array}\right)$

Then this vector can be written in many equivalent ways, say, $\mathbf{A}(p)(1)=\left(\begin{array}{c} y(p)\\  -\sqrt{1-y^2(p)}\\  1\\ \end{array}\right)$, or perhaps $\mathbf{A}(p)(2)=\left(\begin{array}{c} \sqrt{1-x^2(p)}\\  -x(p)\\  1\\ \end{array}\right)$

I get confused here... I mean, the vector is a function of the coordinates, but they are interdependent via $p$.

Am I still allowed to apply the chain rule in its general form

$\frac{d \mathbf{A}}{dp}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dp}+\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dp}+\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dp}$

Is this last expression true? Because this is what happens when I apply it:

$\frac{d \mathbf{A}(1)}{dp}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dp}=\left(\begin{array}{c} -\sin(p)\\  \frac{y \sin(p)}{\sqrt{1-y^2(p)}}\\  0\\ \end{array}\right)$

Which doesn't match

$\frac{d \mathbf{A}(2)}{dp}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dp}=\left(\begin{array}{c} -\frac{x \cos(p)}{\sqrt{1-x^2(p)}}\\  -\cos(p)\\  0\\ \end{array}\right)$

$\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dp}$ should be always the same expression and should not depend on how I chose to write A. But this is not what happens.... The expressions for $\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dp}$ turn out different.

Comment: What are you supposed to do with it? You could simplicity just use p as parameter straight away.

Comment: A is the tangent vector to the curve. I need to check if dA/dp is indeed equal to A' as I am not sure. A' gets into the expression for the curvature.

Comment: Just differentiate x,y,z wrt p and you will get tangent vector in the parameter direction. Then to check how much of the same direction do a scalar product between that vector and A or maybe a projection.

Comment: Yes, this is how I got A. It is the first derivative of the curve position vector.

Comment: I thought A was given as some field you were supposed to check. So what exactly is the question?

Comment: A can be expressed through x(p) and y(p) but the formula for A is not unique. I am unsure if the general chain rule will yield the same d/dp no matter how A is formulated

Comment: I see if it is unclear I can edit it and clarify further

Comment: It is not just unclear, there literally is no question and it is a bit difficult to backtrack the source of the confusion.

Comment: Why introduce square roots instead of simply saying that $\mathbf A(p)=(y(p),-x(p),1)^T$?

Comment: I added more, please see. I am applying the chain rule, and it's not working.

Comment: @amd, I hear you... Your vector is true. I am confused why after I take the dA/dp I get different answers. They depend on how I wrote A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with the multivariable chain rule, I find it easiest to keep things straight by dealing with differentials (total derivatives). Let’s distinguish the function $\overline{\mathbf A}:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ from $\mathbf A:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3$ and call the parameterization of the curve $\gamma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3$. We then have $\mathbf A=\overline{\mathbf A}\circ\gamma$, so $\operatorname{d}\mathbf A_{p}=\operatorname{d}\overline{\mathbf A}_{\gamma(p)}\operatorname{d}\gamma_{p}$. Here, $\operatorname{d}\overline{\mathbf A}$ is just the Jacobean matrix of $\overline{\mathbf A}$ and the other two differentials are the derivatives with respect to $p$. In terms of partial and ordinary derivatives of these functions, then, the chain rule says that $${d\mathbf A\over dp} = \pmatrix{\partial_1\overline{\mathbf A}_1 & \partial_2\overline{\mathbf A}_1 & \partial_3\overline{\mathbf A}_1 \\ 
\partial_1\overline{\mathbf A}_2 & \partial_2\overline{\mathbf A}_2 & \partial_3\overline{\mathbf A}_2 \\
\partial_1\overline{\mathbf A}_3 & \partial_2\overline{\mathbf A}_3 & \partial_3\overline{\mathbf A}_3}{d\gamma\over dp} = 
\pmatrix{\partial_1\overline{\mathbf A}_1{d\gamma_1\over dp} + \partial_2\overline{\mathbf A}_1{d\gamma_2\over dp} + \partial_3\overline{\mathbf A}_1{d\gamma_3\over dp} \\ 
\partial_1\overline{\mathbf A}_2{d\gamma_1\over dp} + \partial_2\overline{\mathbf A}_2{d\gamma_2\over dp} + \partial_3\overline{\mathbf A}_2{d\gamma_3\over dp} \\
\partial_1\overline{\mathbf A}_3{d\gamma_1\over dp} + \partial_2\overline{\mathbf A}_3{d\gamma_2\over dp} + \partial_3\overline{\mathbf A}_3{d\gamma_3\over dp}}$$ or, using your notation and keeping in mind that the partial derivatives of $\mathbf A$ are themselves vectors, $${d\mathbf A\over dp}={\partial\mathbf A\over\partial x}{dx\over dp} + {\partial\mathbf A\over\partial y}{dy\over dp} + {\partial\mathbf A\over\partial z}{dz\over dp}.$$  For the function in your question, we have ${\partial\mathbf A\over\partial x}=(0,-1,0)^T$, ${\partial\mathbf A\over\partial y}=(1,0,0)^T$ and ${\partial\mathbf A\over\partial z}=(0,0,0)^T$, so ${d\mathbf A\over dp}=(-\sin p,-\cos p,0)^T$, just as you’d get by differentiating it directly.

In your computation, you in fact *are* getting the same answer both ways. Continue the calculation by substituting for $x$ and $y$. E.g., $$-{y\sin p\over\sqrt{1-y^2}}=-{\cos p\sin p\over\sqrt{1-\cos^2p}}=-{\cos p\sin p\over\sin p}=-\cos p$$ modulo a sign ambiguity that snuck in when you introduced the square root of a squared quantity into the equations.

Comment: Yes, your proof shows that $\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dp}$ are in the end, the same. But the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial x_i}$ are still ambiguous... Is this to be expected?

Comment: @user142523 The ambiguity lies in the (sloppy) notation. In principle, ${\partial\mathbf A\over\partial x_i}$, or, if you prefer, ${\partial_i\mathbf A}$ is meaningless since $\mathbf A:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^3$. On the other hand, $\partial_i\overline{\mathbf A}$ does makes sense, but that’s strictly speaking a different function. By a common abuse of notation, ${\partial\mathbf A\over\partial x}$ means, approximately, “substitute $x$,$y$ and $z$ into the definition of $\mathbf A$ and then compute a partial derivative relative to $x$.

Comment: Is there a formula to calculate these partial derivatives? Because in the cases of A(1) and A(2) we have one variable only and then the partial is $\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial x} = \frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dp}\frac{dp}{dx}$ which removes the ambiguity. But your vector is A=(y,-x,1) and the above workaround can't be used anymore... What do we do then?

Comment: @user142523 Seems like you might be overthinking this. If $A=(y,-x,1)$, then $\partial A/\partial x$ is simply $(0,-1,0)$. No special formula required. Otherwise, you’re going to have to rely on context to figure out what’s meant by the notation and make appropriate use of the chain rule.